# ember data: Manually send model to updated state

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a ember-data model (parent) that has several embedded models as properties. When I update the embedded models hasMany array the parent does not go to updated/dirty state. How can I manually send the parent to a dirty state?

I have tried the following without luck:

```
parent.set('isDirty', true);
parent.get('stateManager').goToState('dirty')
parent.get('stateManager').goToState('updated.uncommitted')
```

Comment: Just a question... How do you detect a change on the embedded models hasMany array ?

Comment: I had this exact same issue (except my relationships were not embedded). Thank you for the question and the answer! This seems like a bug, doesn't it? If you update the parent's hasMany array, it should be marked dirty. Maybe it just updates the child with the new parent and the child needs to be saved? In my case, the parent's hasMany has a null inverse (child has no parent relationship). Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: @ThomasD You can add an observer method that observes `myHasMany.@each.id` or `myHasMany.length`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not up-to-date with the current situation. Since I posted the message (over a year ago), massive changes happened in ember data. My first guess is that without an inverse the child has no awareness of the parent, thus can not mark the parent as dirty. Consequently, you need to take care on your own. Ember might provide some magic behind the scene to tackle this issue, that I'm not aware of...  If you are interested, you might get direct help at the ember forum at http://discuss.emberjs.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `Ember data` (v1.0.0 > x).

```js
parent.get('stateManager').goToState('updated')
```

Isn't working anymore. **Now you should use**:

```js
parent.transitionTo('updated');
```

---

These is the hierarchy of valid states that ship with ember data:

```
* root
  * deleted
    * saved
    * uncommitted
    * inFlight
  * empty
  * loaded
    * created
      * uncommitted
      * inFlight
    * saved
    * updated
      * uncommitted
      * inFlight
  * loading
```

[Sourece of the states](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RootState.html)

Answer (score 5):

Finally found the solution my self:

```
parent.get('stateManager').goToState('updated')
```

I should also mention that when adding a belongsTo association to the child the parent will be dirtied if the hasMany association is changed. But I still need the manual dirting for the case that a normal property of the child changes.